# JavaScript Dynamic Fade Background Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm trying to change the background image of my application dynamically at an interval of 5 seconds from 5 images and then repeat.

Here's my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var body = $('body');
    var backgrounds = new Array(
      'url(img/bg/bk.jpg)',
      'url(img/bg/nb.jpg)',
      'url(img/bg/la.jpg)',
      'url(img/bg/ts.jpg)',
      'url(img/bg/bh.jpg)'
    );
    var current = 0;
    function nextBackground() {
      body.css(
        'background',
        backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]
      );
      setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    }
    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    body.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
  });
</script>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
body { 
  background: no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Even the background is blank-white.
The `<body>` doesn't have any attributes.

Comment: I copied your code into jsfiddle and it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/7ty2k8zf/ - (testing in Chrome). It's not perfect in that I'm seeing a blank white background in between each image, but you seem to be saying it doesn't work at all?

Comment: Thanks! Seems a problem with FIreFox but i want the image to fully cover the page not get tiled and also to fade.

Comment: Well fully covering the page is a matter of choosing appropriately sized images (I just used placeholders) and/or scaling the image in your CSS. `no-repeat` should stop the tiling (but when you set the background in your JS it's presumably overriding the stylesheet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/powasu/2/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Your script is quite well, I'd change just a couple of things:

CSS:

```
html, body{height:100%;}
body { 
  background: none 50% / cover; /* full background image */
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  var body = $('body');
  var backgrounds = [
    '//placehold.it/800x600/cf5&text=1', // no need to `url(` here
    '//placehold.it/800x600/f1f&text=2',
    '//placehold.it/800x600/333&text=3',
    '//placehold.it/800x600/0f0&text=4',
    '//placehold.it/800x600/70f&text=5'
  ];
  var current = 0;

  // Preload all images // Prevent (if possible) white gaps between image load
  for(var i=0; i<backgrounds.length; i++){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src= backgrounds[i];
  }

  function nextBackground() {
    body.css(
      "background-image", // Use background-image instead of `background`
       "url("+backgrounds[++current % backgrounds.length]+")" // no need to `current = `
    );
    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
  }
  setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
  body.css("background-image", "url("+backgrounds[0]+")");
});
```

For a nice fade EFX you can take a look at this one I've answered half day ago: [Full screen slider with zoom in/out transition effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128700/full-screen-slider-with-zoom-in-out-transition-effect/28128977#28128977)